# What about the tails of a ggplot line graph?

Tags: r, anova, data-visualization, linear-model, ggplot2

Here is my data with value (numeric), group (A/B), Time (T1,T3), and Condition (neutral/reward) variables.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  ID    group time  condition     value
  <chr> <fct> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 Tpp01 A     T1    bias_neutral  61.7 
2 Tpp01 A     T3    bias_neutral -11.4 
3 Tpp01 A     T1    bias_rew     304.  
4 Tpp01 A     T3    bias_rew      33.5 
5 Tpp02 B     T1    bias_neutral -15.5 
6 Tpp02 B     T3    bias_neutral  -8.20
```

Here is my model:

```
aov(value ~ time * condition * group, data = bias_all_long)
```

I am tryting to visualize it by this code:

```
bias_all_long %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = time, y = value, color = group, group = interaction(group, condition)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "solid",
            size = 1, 
            alpha = .7,
            position = position_dodge(width = .1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#0072B2','#CC79A7','#D55E00')) +
  labs(y="Response Times in Ms", x = "Time") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("T1" = "T1", "T3" = "T2")) +
  ylim(-200, +200) +
  facet_wrap(condition~group) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

[image]

First of all, what are those different-sized tails? Why is it like this? How can I solve it? Alternatively, how can I visualize my data better? I know that I can change small things such as legend title, but I am looking for something more fundamental/structural.

Comment: The geom you are using does not seem appropriate for this plot. If you want to compare the distributions of the values by time/condition/group, try `geom_jitter`, `geom_boxplot`, `geom_violin`.

Comment: can you provide a replicable example?